# Проверка существования элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, в нее динамически добавляются строки такого вида:

```
<tr id="2">...</tr>
```

Как проверить в таблице существования строки с атрибутом id=2?

Или как применить функцию jQuery.is(element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>console.log($("tr").is("#2"));</script>
```

возвращает true или false. в данном примере тру

Comment: Странно, у меня так изначально не сработало, поэтому я задал вопрос. Будем искать ошибки.

Comment: прикреплю новым ответом пример. кстати, используйте в работе карту функций, полная, с примерами http://jquery.page2page.ru/tags/ifr.html

Answer (score 3):

`$('tr#2')` — вернёт нужный элемент или пустой список. Следовательно, можно проверять длину возвращаемого списка, тоесть:

```
if($('tr#2').length)
    {/*код для существования элемента*/}
```

Более оптимальный вариант, чем метод `.is()`, предложеный выше, т.к. тут не выполняется вызов ещё одного метода `jQuery`, тут просто запрашивается длина полученого массива.